# How to read temperature from Nokia Health Api?

Tags: javascript, withings

When reading the temperature from the Nokia health API, I am getting the following readings. However, these are not correct. In the Nokia app, the readings in Celsius are as follows:

```
35C { value: 26918, type: 12, unit: -3 }

35.6C { value: 23569, type: 12, unit: -3 }

36.7C { value: 27398, type: 12, unit: -3 }
```

Comment: What's not real? Can you please provide code? what did you try? I'm not sure what is your question

Comment: Yes please provide at least a code snippet. Currently it is not quite clear what you want ...

Comment: The values are not real because in first row, 26918 is some how 35C, I have to derive 35 from 26918 or atleast some thing in human body temperature range.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could gather [from the docs](https://developer.health.nokia.com/api/doc#api-Measure-get_measure):

`value` is the value of the measure. This needs to be used in conjunction with the `unit` parameter to get the correct value.

`type` indicates the measure type. In this case, 12 means temperature

`unit` is the exponential multiplier which needs to be multiplied with the value field to get the actual value in SI units.

Formula:

`actualValue = value * (10 ^ unit)`

Breaking down one of your examples:

`{ value: 26918, type: 12, unit: -3 }`

Here type is 12 so it's temperature (consequently, we can assume the units to be Kelvin if the API returns in SI units)

so, `actualValue = 26918 * (10 ^ -3)` which is `26.918K`

The docs don't explicitly mention what the temperature units are. I have assumed it to be Kelvin because that is the SI unit of temperature. Excerpt from docs:

**Value**

> Value for the measure in S.I units (kilogram, meters, etc.). Value should be multiplied by 10 to the power of "unit" (see below) to get the real value.

**Unit**

> Power of ten the "value" parameter should be multiplied to to get the real value. Eg : value = 20 and unit=-1 means the value really is 2.0

Comment: 26.918K is not in human body temperature range, Those are real data from nokia thermometer. How can we derive ~35C from 26918?

Comment: Yeah, the numbers look way off. Unfortunately, I could not find the units of temperature (type:12) mentioned anywhere in the docs. Perhaps the API is returning some values for a different user than the one being seen on the app?